# Creating a 3x3 matrix with user input numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a 3*3 matrix in python but i need help for user input numbers. I hope someone can help me thank you for that.

```
a = [],[],[] b = [],[],[] c = [],[],[] 
Matrix A = [a,b,c] 
while True: 
   number=input("Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:") 
   [range(3) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: ex :`[range(3) for i in range(3)]`

Comment: Please provide your current code.

Comment: a = [],[],[]
b = [],[],[]
c = [],[],[]
Matrix A  = [a,b,c]
while True:
    number=input("Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:")
    [range(3) for i in range(3)]

Comment: its just an example , based on what kind of matrix you want to create you can use it ,

Comment: can you please enter some numbers in my code and show me?

Comment: @BilalKhan i add an answer !

Comment: OK i tried your code but still it just shows the last number i enter. very very sorry to bother you again and again. i am new to programming :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your array with a nested list comprehension , then you dont need `while` loop just use a nested `for` also you need to convert the input to `int` if you want to store the numbers as int :

```
>>> A=[[[] for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
>>> for i in range(3):
...   for j in range(3):
...     number=int(input("Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:")) 
...     A[i][j]=number
```

Demo :

```
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:1
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:2
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:3
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:3
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:4
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:4
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:5
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:6
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:7
>>> A
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:6
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:-9
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:4
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:1
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:5
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:2
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:22
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:4
Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:5
>>> A
[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], 5]]

Comment: Again its not working with me.

Comment: @BilalKhan maybe you have a bad indentation ! are you copy the code as same as mine ?

Comment: yes i copied the same code

Comment: No you dont , as your code just store the last element (`5`) you have the line `A[i][j]=number` outside the inner loop !

Comment: OK i am trying to fix it

Comment: Thanks A lot . It finally worked. could you tell me about any website from where i could learn python?

Comment: there is many site like http://www.learnpython.org/ ot `python.org` , but i suggest use the O'reilly books series , first use learn python , then programming with python and also python cookbook , those are the best books !

Comment: @BilalKhan you're welcome , you are not a dump , all of the programmers one day was like you !